# Limiting results from TFS WorkItemStore.Query

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Is there a way to limit the amount of workitems that gets returned from WorkItemStore.Query?

workItemStore.Query("Select Title from Issue where (State = 'Active') order by Title") <-- returns quite a few results. For what I'm doing I only want the first 5 results.

Using a query like 
"Select TOP 5 ID, Title from Issue where (State = 'Active') order by Title" 
results in a "Expecting end of string. The error is caused by «5». 
" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck with WIQL in this case.  A couple things come to mind-- you could do a database query against the TFSWorkItemTracking database, or you could use another limiting factor (last updated date, create date, etc.).